# Squid Proxy Server Admin Interface

Tags: linux, security, proxy, open-source, squid

My client has Squid proxy server and it is working fine. But to see the access log and other changes, we have to go through only with Command prompt. Moreover I am new to the Squid server.

Client wants me to check for Administrative interface to see how many people are using Squid server? To get know the browser information they logging? And other data like Webalizer.

So my question is, is there any admin interface to install in Squid server?

Comment: do you have full access to the box? `squid` has some basic internal stats which can be accessed via `http` or `snmp`

Comment: Yes.. i have full access on the box.

Answer (score 2):

Squid cache provides a basic web interface for stats via [Cache Manager](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CacheManager).

Presuming you have a default install start by checking for the following file which you will need to edit to allow yourself access to the interface by setting the `allow from` line;

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/squid.conf`

Once you have reloaded your web server config you should be able to navigate too; `http://<your host>/cgi-bin/cachemgr.cgi`

You should then be able to access a number of stats and counters.

If you prefer `squid` also supports `snmp` via the config file at; `/etc/squid/squid.conf` where in you should add the following section (Customising as required)

```
snmp_port 3401
acl snmppublic snmp_community public
snmp_access allow snmppublic
snmp_access deny all
snmp_incoming_address 0.0.0.0
snmp_outgoing_address 255.255.255.255
```

Information and the OID values can be found in the docs [here](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Snmp).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will that work even if i don't have apache on the server? Because i was trying to add "allow from" as they mentioned in the url https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ManagerCgiTool. Looks like i need Apache on the server to be installed.

Comment: Yes.. Its dependant on some web-server (doesn't need to be apache though.)  If you can't use the web version you may be better off looking at the `snmp` stuff instead - that way you only need the client to connect and pull the data - then you could display however you like.